# How to call function in button onclick?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi here i added one stackblitz link. In that sample, i added my tool-bar and i provided required value in one array variable, and I added one button also.

My question is if i click that button the array variable values have to append in new array variable?

I added this function:

```js
//old array variable

 tbarArray = [
    { text: "Cut" },
    { text: "Copy" },
    { text: "Paste" },
    { text: "Underline" },
    { text: "Italic" },
    { text: "Color" },
    { text: "Numbering" },
    { text: "Ascending" },
    { text: "Descending" },
    { text: "Indent" },
    { text: "Outdent" },
  ];

// new array variable
  newarray = [];
  
  // function
  public run() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      let check: any = this.tbarArray[i];
      this.newarray[i] = check;
    }
  }
```

And this is sample link:
[sample link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbnkcr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: use `(click)="run()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClick event will search the function at the application level, not the function declared at the component level.

To invoke the function defined at the component level, use the click event:

```
<button style="margin-right: 5px" (click)="run()" type="submit">add</button>
```

Comment: did you try this?